# Получение элемента из коллекций

Tags: java, коллекции

Доброго времени суток.

```
 public class Info{
   String name;
   Double price;
  }
```

Есть класс на котором созданы несколько коллекций. Каждая коллекция хранит часть данных, например одна хранит только название (String name), другая цену (Double price). Как после добавление в коллекции, например искать цену по названию? Создавать новую коллекцию и добавлять туда все элементы из коллекций  думаю не выход.
Если есть где можно прочесть про это, скиньте ссылку. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `одна хранит только название (String name), другая цену (Double price).` - совсем плохая идея. Особенно если там нет сопоставления индексов один к одному. Правильным решением было бы изначально делать коллекцию `Info` и только так

Comment: Я понял, просто хочу узнать можно ли так сделать и как реализовать.

Comment: можно. но это самая плохая идея из всех плохих идей

Comment: "Каждая коллекция хранит часть данных, например одна хранит только название (String name), другая цену (Double price)." - как они связанны? Как понять какому названию соответствует конкретная цена?                                                                                                             "Как после добавление в коллекции, например искать цену по названию?" - для этого лучше использовать мапу

Answer (score 4):

Разные коллекции с именами и ценами - просто жуткий костылище и наиневернейший способ делать это. Один из подходящих способов реализации указан ниже:

```
class Info{
    String name;
    Double price;
    public Info(String name, Double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    //------ Список с данными Info
    List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    infoList.add(new Info("test", 1.1));
    infoList.add(new Info("test", 1.33));
    infoList.add(new Info("test22", 2.1));
    infoList.add(new Info("test3", 3.1));
    infoList.add(new Info("te1st", 33.1));

    String searchName = "test";

    //------ Java8 реализация поиска нужных данных
    List<Info> foundedInfoList = infoList
        .stream()
        .filter(el -> el.name.equals(searchName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //------ Как итог: посмотреть все полученные цены
    for (Info info : foundedInfoList) {
        System.out.println(info.name + ", " + info.price);
    }
}
```

А если интересует лишь цены у тех, у кого имя совпало, то:

```
double[] doubles = infoList
            .stream()
            .filter(el -> el.name.equals(searchName))
            .mapToDouble(el -> el.price)
            .toArray();

//  Вывод всех цен
for (Double d : doubles) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

---

Но если интересует именно вариант **как делать не надо**, то выглядит он так:

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
namesList.add("test");
namesList.add("test22");
namesList.add("test3");
namesList.add("test");
namesList.add("tewerst");
List<Double> pricesList = new ArrayList<>();
pricesList.add(1.1);
pricesList.add(1.2);
pricesList.add(1.3);
pricesList.add(1.4);

String searchName = "test";

ArrayList<Integer> indexesOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
// Выбираем все индексы в списке, в которых совпадает namr  с поиском
for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
    if (searchName == namesList.get(i)) {
        indexesOfNames.add(i);
    }
}
// из списка с ценами выбираем по тем же индексам
for (int i = 0; i < pricesList.size(); i++) {
    for (Integer indexesOfName : indexesOfNames) {
        if (indexesOfName == i) {
            System.out.println(pricesList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне просто интересно как реализовать "связь" между коллекциями, тут ясно что лучше все данные хранить в одной выбранной коллекции. В интернете искал но ничего нет, скорее всего плохо искал, но если у вас есть источник где можно подобное почитать, поделитесь ссылкой, буду благодарен.

Comment: @HiHello если хранить в одной коллекции только имена, а в другой только цены, то коллекции должны быть строго 1 к 1.... то есть по первому индексу одной коллекции должно быть соответствие первому индексу второй коллекции...2-ой ко второму, третий к третьему и т.д... Больше никак.......Соответственно если у тебя по имени "test" в первой коллекции будет индекс 666, то во второй коллекции стоит искать на 666 позиции

Comment: То есть должна быть одинаковая размерность + коллекции должны иметь индекс(например Tree в котором нет индексов, такого при большом желании не сделаешь).

Comment: @HiHello добавил неправильный вариант со списком (который ты и хочешь)......`TreeSet` не имеет смысла уже, т.к. это упорядоченная коллекция.... Как только ты добавишь элементы в две разные коллекции - они уже не будут совпадать по индексам.. Поэтому только в неупорядоченные придется заносить......да, коллекции, что логично, должны иметь одинаковый размер

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь и за потраченное время.